# IndexOutOfRange unless I split the query into multiple queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, indexoutofrangeexception

I've written a SQL query for my C# program but when I try to run the query I get this error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException:

I tried to alter the query order to see if that was the only one doing it, and I noticed that it only gave me that error when I had code in the `while (DRorder.Read())` that tried to convert at least 2 of these 3 columns (`ADRES`, `LEV`, `TAAL`).

```
// the code that gives the error    
SqlCommand getlist = new SqlCommand("select * from BESW where BEST = @best", Connectie.connMEVO);
getlist.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;

DRorder = getlist.ExecuteReader();

while (DRorder.Read())
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["BESTEL"]);
    dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["PLAN"]);
    comboBox2.Text = DRorder["ADRES"].ToString();
    comboBox1.Text = DRorder["LEV"].ToString();
    textBox8.Text = DRorder["TAAL"].ToString();
}
```

However when I split the query into 3 near identical queries with each one of the 3 columns that could give an error, it suddenly works without any issue.

```
// this is the code that im currently using without error    
SqlCommand getlist = new SqlCommand("select BESTEL, [PLAN], ADRES from BESW where BEST = @best", Connectie.connMEVO);
getlist.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;

DRorder = getlist.ExecuteReader();

while (DRorder.Read())
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["BESTEL"]);
    dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["PLAN"]);
    comboBox2.Text = DRorder["ADRES"].ToString();
}

SqlCommand getlist2 = new SqlCommand("select LEV from BESW where BEST = @best", Connectie.connMEVO);
getlist2.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;

DRorder = getlist2.ExecuteReader();

while (DRorder.Read())
{
    comboBox1.Text = DRorder["LEV"].ToString();
}

SqlCommand getlist3 = new SqlCommand("select TAAL from BESW where BEST = @best", Connectie.connMEVO);
getlist3.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;

DRorder = getlist3.ExecuteReader();

while (DRorder.Read())
{
    textBox8.Text = DRorder["TAAL"].ToString();
}
```

I have no idea as to why it does this, since all the other queries in my program work, I even have queries that read that entire table and those don't give any problems with having those fields in the `while` loop.

Now my question is, why does one of these code blocks work while the other gives an error? And perhaps if one knows a solution to this I'd like to hear it, since I feel like it's better to have it all into 1 query.

I do know I forgot to put the `Dispose` of the queries in these code blocks.

Additional information about the problem: when I run the single query code the column that gives the error is `LEV` but if I change the order of the columns, the problem will be given by the second column listed out of these 3 (`ADRES`, `LEV`, `TAAL`).

EDIT: "new" code (DB has 28 columns)

```
// the code that gives the error    
SqlCommand getlist = new SqlCommand("select * from BESW where BEST = @best", Connectie.connMEVO);
getlist.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;

DRorder = getlist.ExecuteReader();

while (DRorder.Read())
{
    if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(10)) { dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder[10]); }
    if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(11)) { dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder[11]); }
    if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(7)) { comboBox1.Text = DRorder[7].ToString(); }
    if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(8)) { comboBox2.Text = DRorder[8].ToString(); }
    if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(25)) { textBox8.Text = DRorder[25].ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: This isn't a SQL Server error, you are using the wrong index number or key somewhere

Comment: Even if that is the case, what I don't get is why the it works in 3 seperate queries but not if I put them into a single query.

Comment: Why are you breaking the query in three identical queries? You don't gain anything but you end up doing three round trips

Comment: That's why im curious as to why it works when I do it in 3 steps, but it breaks as soon as I do it in 1 or 2.

Comment: As for why - did you try debugging? In which line does the error occur? Add a watch with the call that fails, eg. `DrOrder[10]`. Inspect the value of `DrOrder` to see which columns it *does* contain. Also check DROrder.FieldCount, is it what you expected?

Comment: It only gives the error if I have at least 2 of these 3 columns in the same query (`LEV`,`ADRES`,`TAAL`). The line the error occurs in is the line that has the second column of the three stated.

Comment: the moment the code hits ` if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(8))` it goes the the `catch`. as to what is in the reader I don't quite know how to see that, since with a breakpoint all i get is a whole load of data but nothing that looks like the column data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the reason it didn't work as 1 query was that the comboboxes I was filling fired the `TextChange event` during the query and due to that overwriting the reader.

Answer (score 1):

this query

```
select BESTEL,[PLAN],ADRES from BESW where BEST=@best
```

returns only 3 columns, and you can't take `DRorder["LEV"]`,  `DRorder["TAAL"]`

include TAAL and LEV in the 1st SELECT

```
SqlCommand getlist = new SqlCommand("select BESTEL,[PLAN],ADRES, LEV, TAAL from BESW where BEST=@best", Connectie.connMEVO);
```

UPDATE

IndexOutOfRangeException means that "No column with the specified name was found."

try take value by index

```
comboBox1.Text = DRorder[3].ToString();
textBox8.Text = DRorder[4].ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry that was a error on my part that only existed in this post, I had to remake the single query out of the 3 smaller ones and forgot to change the columns. In the code it does try to get each column and it still gives the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately it seems that it is not that simple for the columns do exist when they are called upon each in their own query, the error is only given when 2 or more of those 3 specific columns get called upon in the same query

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit column names in the select query:

```
select BESTEL, PLAN, ADRES, LEV, TAAL from ...
```

and/or, as @Ash pointed out, retrieve the columns using index:

```
comboBox1.Text = DRorder[3].ToString();
```

Unrelated, but might I also suggest:

```
if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(3)) comboBox1.Text = DRorder[3].ToString();
```

Edit, remote-debugging:

```
try
{

    DRorder = getlist.ExecuteReader();

    while (DRorder.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BESTEL: " + DRorder.GetOrdinal("BESTEL").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("PLAN: " + DRorder.GetOrdinal("PLAN").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("ADRES: " + DRorder.GetOrdinal("ADRES").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("LEV: " + DRorder.GetOrdinal("LEV").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("TAAL: " + DRorder.GetOrdinal("TAAL").ToString());

        if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(10)) { dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder[10]); }
        if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(11)) { dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder[11]); }
        if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(7)) { comboBox1.Text = DRorder[7].ToString(); }
        if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(8)) { comboBox2.Text = DRorder[8].ToString(); }
        if (!DRorder.IsDBNull(25)) { textBox8.Text = DRorder[25].ToString(); }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

I assume you're not accessing DRorder outside the scope of the .read(), and that no other action is manipulating the data while this is getting called.

Can you report back what the above code outputs?

Comment: I have tried the using the explicit column names but even that didn't change a thing, trying to retrieve them using the column number gives me the same error and for the `if` statement im guessing it is to prevent empty cells/rows? I doubt that it changes a thing since those fields can't be empty. (I'll give it a try though)

Comment: @maam27 Is there any other info in your error message. Sounds like it would either be a faulty sql column reference or a c# array-like error. Neither explains why it works if you separate the queries though.

Comment: I have it so it tries to read it by column number and now it says this: `Invalid attempt to read when no data is present`. I did add the if statement for each of the columns and I know for certain that the column is filled, for the query I have to fill it won't allow any of those to be empty

Comment: Sounds like you're using an out-of-bounds index. Can you update your question with the "new" code?

Comment: i tried the above code, it does not go into an error on the printlines but it still gives it on the textbox. the values it says in the console are : `bestel: 9`, `plan: 10`, `adres: 7`, `lev: 6`, `taal: 24`. also perhaps it's better to go into a chat? for there are already quite a bit of comments

Comment: so you're using the wrong indexes. This is a zero-based system, so start from 0 and change them accordingly. Sure, fire up a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74235/discussion-between-mackan-and-maam27).

Comment: have an upvote for helping to find the issue and solving it, and for the debug codes for they did help me find it.